# Immediately Invoked Function Expression in strict mode

Tags: javascript

In strict mode can't we use Immediately Invoked Function Expressions(IIFE)?
Following program proves that I can't use IIFE in strict mode. If I comment 'use strict' it works. Was this because of the reason that every expression in strict mode must have a name?

```
'use strict'
(function _test () {
var obj = {`enter code here`
        a:      2,
        b:      'name',
        c:      function _c (){
                console.log('a: ' + this.a + " b: "+ this.b);
        }
};
obj.c();
}) ();
```

Following is the output

```
(function _test () {
^
TypeError: string is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ganesh/temp/let.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module.`enter code here`_extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

Comment: You left off the semicolon after `'use strict'`.

Comment: @Pointy I thought of the same, but automatic semicolon insertion should add it, right? Or something in the expression after it is preventing it?

Comment: @Tushar no!!  That's not a place where semicolon insertion would happen, as should be clear from the error message. The parser is interpreting the code as `<expression>(parameters)` because of the `( )` around the function. But the string `'use strict'` is not a function, and thus the error.

Comment: Semicolon insertion is weird and only happens in specific circumstances.

Comment: @Pointy That's the explanation I was looking for, this should be an answer so that users know what is actually happening.

Comment: *"Was this because of the reason that every expression in strict mode must have a name?"* Expressions don't have "names".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main problem is the missing semicolon after `use strict`.
When the JS engine examine the lexical structure of your code, it sees `'use strict'` and then the `(` so it expects a function of the form `name()`.

One of the rules for automatic semicolon insertion states:

> Semicolons are only ever inserted when the next input token cannot be 
>   parsed

which gives 5 problematic characters to watch out for:

`(, [, +, -, and /` all **DISABLE** semicolon insertion

If a statement on the next line begins with these characters and the previous line is missing a semicolon the two lines will be treated as a single line by the engine and this is quite error prone.

if you remove the `enter code here` part added by SO and add a semicolon after `use strict`, everything works.

```js
'use strict';
(function _test() {
  var obj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 'name',
    c: function _c() {
      console.log('a: ' + this.a + " b: " + this.b);
    }
  };
  obj.c();
})();
```